# Can't convert text to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

I have the following code (Be patient I'm not at all a Javascript Programmer)

I've been able to load the concerning text files but am unable to convert them to an array could somebody please explain?

```
function Login(form) {

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    USRFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users.txt", 1, false, 0);
    var USR_LIST = USRFile.Read(1000)
var USRitems = USR_LIST.split(",");
    USRFile.Close();
    fso = null;

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    PWDFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\passwords.txt", 1, false, 0);
    var PWD_LIST = PWDFile.Read(1000)
var PWDitems = PWD_LIST.split(",");
    PWDFile.Close();
    fso = null;

username = new Array(USRitems);
password = new Array(PWDitems);
page = "SETTINGS.html";
if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0] || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1] || form.username.value == username[2] && form.password.value == password[2] || form.username.value == username[3] && form.password.value == password[3] || form.username.value == username[4] && form.password.value == password[4] || form.username.value == username[5] && form.password.value == password[5] || form.username.value == username[6] && form.password.value == password[6] || form.username.value == username[7] && form.password.value == password[7] || form.username.value == username[8] && form.password.value == password[8] || form.username.value == username[9] && form.password.value == password[9]) {
self.location.href = page;
}
else {
page = "Access_Violation.html";
self.location.href = page;
form.username.focus();
}
return true;
}
```

I have the following in the text Password.txt file

```
"p1","p2","p3"
```

and for the User.txt I have

```
"u1","u2","u3"
```

I just can't get the array???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have both in array form

```
var USRitems = USR_LIST.split(",");
```

And

```
var PWDitems = PWD_LIST.split(",");
```

Are arrays with the values. The **split** function is doing that. This is how it works :

```
string.split([separator][, limit])
```

**Parameters**

**separator**
    Specifies the character(s) to use for separating the string. The separator is treated as a string or a regular expression. If separator is omitted, the array returned contains one element consisting of the entire string. If separator is an empty string, string is converted to an array of characters.

**limit**
    Integer specifying a limit on the number of splits to be found. The split method still splits on every match of separator, but it truncates the returned array to at most limit elements.

You can read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: I can't check if your code works or not, since I'm not on windows. But on your code you have the values in an array already, you don't need to use `username = new Array(USRitems);` you can just do `username = USRitems`. Also, you should do a loop instead of having all in a single if.

Answer (score 1):

`split` returns an array. When you do this:

```
username = new Array(USRitems);
```

You're putting the array you already have in a new array.

You simply just want to do:

```
username = USRItems
```

Example:

```
var array = [1,2,3];
console.log(array);
var array2 = new Array(array);
console.log(array2);
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3]] // note the extra brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = string.split(',',2);
```